# How shoud be a parameters table designed and used on businesses and GUI layers?

Tags: design-patterns, business-logic, architecture

I'm currently designing an application and I need to know how should be designed a constants parameter table. Also, I want to know how to use this table on the application.

For example: for a parameter sex (M or F) in a system, it should be in its own table or is better to have that parameter with others in a special table?. How can I "envelope" parameters in the subsequent layers (using a constants class with the parameters and their primary keys)?

I have heard about a special "DB pattern" or a common way to create a table such that its schema lets the development process to relay on this single parameter table. Do you know how's this called?

Also... could you recommend me any good bibliography on the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've built and used many times what I call [Parameter Enumeration Tables](http://chateau-logic.com/content/parameter-enumeration-tables). The [module](http://zxaf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zxaf/trunk/cbf/params.php?revision=24&view=markup) is part of my [ZXAF opensource framework](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zxaf/).

Basic design is simple, you have a `Parameters` table that has a 1-many relationship with each table that needs a parametrised field. It looks something like this:

[image]

Expanding on this to provide a real example, where we are working with a `users` table that contains a `status` field.  We index and link the field to the `params` table via a *constraint* as follows;

```
INDEX `FK_user_status` (`status`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_user_status` FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `params` (`id`) 
           ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

*NOTE: I'm using `CASCADE` here, there are times when you don't want to do this*

This gives us the following schema;

[image]

The key concept of this is to allow the database to contain parameterised data that maintains referential integrity, and integrates with a data model within the code. The code is able to find out by querying the database how entities are related, and for example what the valid values for a specific field are.

[image: Parameter Enumeration Tables sample schema]

Lastly I want to introduce and explain the concept of *Parameters [Tuples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple)*. This is another table that allows us to associate a pair of parameters (the Tuple) with a value. This a data neutral way in which we can extend `PET` provide the lookup and expected values. This is most suited to an extensible model where it is possible to add new enumerations, and yet we need to allow them to contain a value. *It is often better to do this with *relationships**

[image: Parameters schema with Tuples]

I'm not in [favour of enums in databases](http://chateau-logic.com/content/why-we-should-not-use-enums-databases), but this is only my opinion and it may be something that you're happy with.

Comment: I do have a question about this design pattern. Looking at the article referenced, it has a `symbol` field and a comment that says it's used in the code. 
Assuming the symbol from the insert would be `TRANSACTION_TYPE_PENDING`. What benefit does the symbol bring?

Comment: The symbol allows usage of param values in PHP by way of a constant. During startup all param records that have a symbol have a constant setup. ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php. 
This gives an easy way to use the param table without having to look things up and makes params work more like static enums.

Answer (score 1):

I use a model similar in nature to what Richard Harrison posted. [image: Design]

Your code table can simplify matters if you have a handful of states specific to a subset of tables, but if these states aren't shared or needed by other parts of your database, then you risk making the code table even more confusing by storing everything in one place. This is a judgment call you'll have to make for yourself -- in my current application, I use one centralized Code table because the database is so small.

As for what you store here: I only keep records in the database of data that might change based on business needs. Some examples of this:

- Shipping destinations (you might only ship to a few states in the US, or a handful of countries in a particular region, etc.)
- Order status codes.
- Application roles.

If you anticipate changing the answer to a "sex" question from only M/F to Male, Female, Transgendered (or something like that, although strictly speaking we're now talking about gender rather than sex), or accommodating other genders, then I'd suggest including it in your database. Otherwise, for something that's as close to permanent as you can get, don't store it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Most applications use an "enumeration". How you use these enums are wholly dependant on how the application is implemented.

Unless you are catering for more than just "M" and "F" genders, I'd put those two options in their own table.

You would "envelope" parameters in subsequent layers by writing a binding, which may or may not use some kind of marshalling. This is wholly dependant on how you implement the application.

Comment: How is that binding and marshalling done? do you know any "pattern" or "common practice" to design a general parameter table (ie. having all parameters in one application)?

Comment: Can you automatize the marshalling or unmarshalling process? i.e. generate parameters from a DB table in runtime? or, which pattern can be useful to get the constants binded?

Comment: That entirely depends on the tools your language and framework provides.  In python, it can be nearly completely automated. C# (and other .NET languages) offer some tools that provide some automation. Others such as C provide no opportunities whatsoever for safe automatic marshalling unless the framework has been specifically designed to contain transparent marshalling support.

Comment: Can you enumerate some C# tools?

Comment: At risk of sounding condescending, I would like you to simply get a book (any book) about C#. It's part of the language.

Comment: By using something like introspection??. Yes... I know there are some tools, but I'm not yet fully accustomed to C#, therefore I want to see some examples... thanks for your patience!

Comment: public enum MyEnumeration { Male; Female; Undecided; }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for what is called a [Dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_table) table. This is related to [SCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_Changing_Dimension)s. One of these could be your "single parameter table". With time you might find it's better to have multiple tables (sex, location, etc.)